# Как дотянуться до определённого ребенка родителя в разных списках

Tags: html, css, gulp, less

Как с помощью `less` переписать `css`?

Есть существующий проект с внутренними стилями в `html` и подключенным файлам `css`, как включить less в проект не переписывая заново `css`, а поправить стили из `less` с помощью `npm gulp`

Comment: в проекте только есть css, без less?

Comment: Да, еше и в html стили прописаны но они мне так важны

Comment: Есть же куча онлайн транспайлеров css-> less/sass/scss/stylus

Comment: а додать свои файл .css в head по ниже основного не лутше? если нет возможности самому вписать, можна через js, добавить.

Comment: Так тоже можно но в проэкте и так г-код, пока получилось переписать css изходник переписывать с помощью gulp